# why two equal ranges are different objects in cpython?

Tags: python, object, cpython

I am wondering why

```
a = "abcdghf23"
b = "abcdghf23"

c = range(100)
d = range(100)

e = []
f = []
```

`a is b` retruns True

while `c is d` returns False

and `e is f` returns False

actually the question is why id of a and b are the same but id of the rest is different.

they are all iterables.

a b c d are immutable

e and f are mutable

Cannot figure out the pattern and the cause of this

Comment: Python can cache the strings because it knows they are immutable. Its a special case for the compiler. It has no such knowledge of the `range` object.

Comment: Honestly, the `is` operator is nearly useless and should be tossed from your thinking.  Virtually the ONLY legitimate use is in the test  `if x is None:`.

Comment: `range` is a type. `c` and `d` are *instances* of that type, and those instances are independent, even if created with the same argument.